# Issue: How can I chain a function after an async Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular component that allows doing the selection of an item in a list. So, `onInit()` should do the following:

1. Load a list of data asynchronously
2. Set, by default, the first element of that list of data as selected

The *promisified* way of achieving this desired behavior, would be:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // 1) Load list of items (async)
   this.loadItems()
      // 2) after async load, set default selected item
      .then(this.setDefaultSelectedItem);
}

// Calls the Service and sets `this.items` when the requested list
loadItems() {
   return this.itemsService.getAll()
      .then((items) => this.items = items);
}

this.setDefaultSelectedItem() {
   // first item on the list of items by default
   this.selectedItem = this.items[0]; 
}
```

I am trying to achieve the same using `rxjs` and `Observables`. So far I have done the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // 1) load list of pharmacies
   this.loadItems();
   // 2) select as default the first one (TODO)
}

loadItems() {
   return this.itemsService.getAll()
      .subscribe(items => this.items = items);
}

this.setDefaultSelectedItem() {
   // first item on the list of items by default
   this.selectedItem = this.items[0]; 
}
```

I have been doing some research lately, read about `flatMap()`... but I haven't been capable of chaining `setDefaultSelectedItem()` after `loadItems()`, and I'm stuck there.

#### Update:

I would like to avoid having the content of `this.setDefaultSelectedItem()` inside the `.subscribe()` block like this:

```
loadItems() {
   return this.itemsService.getAll()
      .subscribe(items => {
         this.items = items;
         this.selectedItem = this.items[0];
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{}` in the `subscribe()` method you can achieve one than more thing!

```
loadItems() {
   return this.pharmaciesService.getAll()
      .subscribe(items => {
        this.items = items;
        this.setDefaultSelectedItem();
      });
}
```

---

Edit:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // 1) load list of pharmacies
   this.loadItems().subscribe(() => { 
     // 2) select as default the first one (TODO)
     this.setDefaultSelectedItem() 
   });
}

loadItems() {
   let obs = this.itemsService.getAll();
   obs.subscribe(items => this.items = items);
   return obs;

}

this.setDefaultSelectedItem() {
   // first item on the list of items by default
   this.selectedItem = this.items[0]; 
}
```

Comment: Sure I knew that, but I'd like to keep logic in small single responsibility blocks. I want `loadItems()` just to load the items, instead of doing everything (selecting default also in this case). That would solve my problem, of course, but I'd like to know how to be able to chain functions using Observables. What if instead of being a one line function (`this.selectedItem = this.items[0]`) there were more complicated logic there? I want to achieve it in separate functions, and therefore chain them.

Comment: Check the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 -

```
loadPharmacies() { 
  return this.pharmaciesService.getAll() 
    .subscribe(
      items => this.items = items;
      this.setDefaultSelectedItem();
    ); 
}
```

Solution 2 -

```
 loadPharmacies() { 
  return this.pharmaciesService.getAll() 
    .subscribe({
      error: err => console.log(`Oops... ${err}`), 
      complete: () => console.log(`Complete!`), 
    }); 
}
```

Then in complete method you can do whatever you want to do.

If you have any doubt do let me know.